# Is there an intent to launch Android Market to "My Apps" page?

Tags: android, google-play, android-intent

Like the title says.  Is there an intent to launch android market to the "My Apps" page?
I have a dialog that displays if the app is out of date.  I'd like to put a button on the dialog that leads directly to the "My Apps" page so the user can download the update.

**Edit:** For clarity, I'm not talking about the details page for my app.  I'm talking about the "My Apps" section of the Android Market application.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See this: http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/publishing.html#marketintent for everything you want to know.

EDIT: try this. Do note that this might change if the Market app is updated to use a different activity.

```
Intent i = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW");
            i.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.android.vending","com.android.vending.MyDownloadsActivity"));
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(i);
```

Comment: I'm aware of the search and details intents.  Do you know if there is an update button on the details page for an app?

Comment: If you've released a new version there will be an Update button.

Comment: So, there doesn't appear to be an "update" button on my apps details page when I go there using the details intent.  Back to the original question then, is it possible to use an intent to go straight to the "My Apps" page in the Android Market? Just so I'm being clear - I don't mean the page for my app, I mean the "My Apps" section of the Android Market application.

Comment: Excellent!  Sorry for the delay I didn't realize you had edited your answer.

Comment: Got `ActivityNotFoundException` on my device

Answer (score 2):

[This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28692634/1580487) has been working for me flawlessly across many Gplay versions so far. Here's a summary:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.android.finsky.VIEW_MY_DOWNLOADS");
intent.setClassName("com.android.vending", "com.google.android.finsky.activities.MainActivity");
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: WORKING! Tested on 2 Android 4.4.2 devices and a nexus with 6.0.1. It does open playstore and jumps to my apps where you can press update button. Even if playstore is already open on other page it will jump to my apps. Why this answer was downvoted I cannot understand. This should be the accepted answer for all devices between 4.4.2 and 6.0.1 I guess?!

Answer (score -1):

The latest version of Play Store app is fragment based. You cannot open the "My Apps" because it's hosted in the same activity as the rest of fragments. The best you can do is to open the main activity and let user navigate to the "My Apps".

```
    Intent marketIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
            .setComponent(new ComponentName("com.android.vending", 
                    "com.google.android.finsky.activities.MainActivity"))
            .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(marketIntent);
```