# Android intent to google play app at "my applications" section

Tags: android, android-intent, google-play

Is possible to launch a intent to Google play store app to show "my applications" section?? I need to watch current apps and updates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some painful retro-engineering...

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.android.finsky.VIEW_MY_DOWNLOADS");
intent.setClassName("com.android.vending", "com.google.android.finsky.activities.MainActivity");
startActivity(intent);
```

Edit:
*That works for now (Version : 5.2.13) but **Google** may change this behavior in a future release*